# I'm trying to do my own custom user provider,In Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to do my own custom user provider,In Symfony tutorial From
"http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-class" This Site Tutorial But Couldn't Understand how to implement This site code in my localhost.Pleace help me some step by step process or a video process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class that implements this interface

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface
```

For that, you must create a public function called `loadUserByUserName` that receives as a parameter a string (the user name) then you have to implement the logic to get the user entity (you may need to call Doctrine and find it on the database or make some calls to an API...) whatever service you need must be injected.

You also have to implement the method `refreshUSer()` that I'm not sure when is used.

and finally, the `suportsClass` method that checks if a given `classname` is supported (usually you have to check it against your user class `classname`)

Once done, you have to setup this class as a service in tour `services.yml` file. Remember to inject here the dependencies (with setters or using the constructor, this is up to you)

Comment: After Do This All That According to this tutorial and as you said, What I wrote in my localhost url to get that security login page.

Comment: You should point to your login page. are you using FosUseBundle?